# Fullcalendar - draggable events hides while dragging?

Tags: jquery-ui, css, jquery-selectors, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalendar plugin. To be clear, I am not too good in css. The issue that I am facing is that when I drag the event from external-events div then the event that I drag hides while dragging on the cell. I don't know which property of css needs to be change in order to make the draggable event visible while dragging from external-events div. I tried to set 'display:block' for the 'external-event' class but it does not make the event visible while dragging. Any help is greatly appreciable. Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you create an example in http://jsfiddle.net for better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove **overflow:hidden** from `.widget` DIV. Write like this:

```
.widget{
 overflow:visible;
}
```